# Are there any awards for Sci-Fi miniseries?

Tags: awards

Sci-Fi miniseries typically rock, because they mix the conciseness - closer to a movie - with the volume of content that would take a TV show a season or more to produce.  If you look for Sci-Fi mini-series or awards, Google mostly just lists random forum posts and individual Sci-Fi mini-series.  So I figure that if I can find any type of Awards given to Sci-Fi miniseries, I can check that out for new material to check out.

Are there any Awards for Sci-Fi miniseries?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think so.  My google-fu is turning up no more than yours and I've never heard of one.  Miniseries tend to be grouped in with either Film, Television or both.  Which seems pretty reasonable.  There aren't exactly enough of them for Sci-Fi miniseries to really merit their own award or award category.